# Racket: lexical scope inside for

Tags: racket, list-comprehension, lexical-scope

In Haskell, inside a list comprehension, i can bind expressions to a variable every iteration:

```
[a | x <- xs, let a = x ^ 2, a >= 25]
```

How do i bind lexical variables in Racket's `for` comprehension?

Currently i have this code:

```
(define (euler4)
  (apply max
         (for*/list ([i (in-range 100 1000)]
                     [j (in-range i 1000)]
                     #:when (string=? (number->string (* i j))
                                      (string-reverse (number->string (* i j)))))
           (* i j))))
```

I want to bound `(* i j)` to a variable and replace the expression to it everywhere in function.

Comment: While the question and answer is valid, I'm bummed that you basically posted an answer to Project Euler #4 and I stumbled across this while trying to solve it in Racket. Euler specifically asks that you not do this. I added the project-euler tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`in-value`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-value%29%29) form to have a loop variable that is bound to a single value.

In your example:

```
(define (euler4)
  (apply max
         (for*/list ([i (in-range 100 1000)]
                     [j (in-range i 1000)]
                     [ij (in-value (* i j))]
                     #:when (string=? (number->string ij)
                                      (string-reverse (number->string ij))))
           (* i j))))
```

Comment: Nice! didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 1):

These days in modern versions of Racket (defined as 8.5 and newer), `for` comprehensions have a `#:do [do-body ...]` clause that lets you do things like define variables. So you might write it as

```lisp
(define (euler4)
  (apply max
         (for*/list ([i (in-range 100 1000)]
                     [j (in-range i 1000)]
                     #:do [(define ij (* i j))
                           (define ij-str (number->string ij))]
                     #:when (string=? ij-str (string-reverse ij-str)))
           ij)))
```

Comment: (I'd use `for*/fold` instead and calculate the maximum as it goes instead of splitting that off into a second step, but that sort of optimization isn't really the point here.)

Comment: Old question, but if someone else stumbles across it, might as well show a modern approach.